# Reset textbox value in Infopath form each time it is opened?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

How can I have the Infopath form automatically reset the value of a textbox to "no" each time the form is opened?

Programatically I assume is the best answer, but I'm a complete newbie, please be specific! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to tools -> Form Options -> Rules and create a rule with the action to set that textbox to "no."

This means that if you save a form and re-open it, the value will change to "no."  If you simply wanted new forms to start out with the value "no", you would right click that box and set the default value.

Comment: Clarification: Tools->Form Options->Open and Save->Rules.